# How to rotate an iPhone app when used on an iPad in landscape

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

Devices is set to "iPhone" under Deployment info. In my Info.plist I have iPhone as Portrait only, and iPad as all 4 options. My app works fine on iPhone (no rotation as expected). It behaves the same on an iPad (no rotation) but of course then to view the app properly I have to hold the iPad like an iPhone with the Home button at the button. I don't want to have to do that. What I want is when the iPad is in landscape, e.g. with a keyboard, for the app to rotate but maintain its iPhone-like appearance, smaller, in the center of the display. How to achieve this?

Comment: iPhone emulation on an iPad has no support for rotating the emulated iPhone if the iPad is held in landscape orientation. You would think it would though since the screen is large enough. File an enhancement request.